# Is there a docker compose service naming convention?

Tags: node.js, docker, naming-conventions, docker-compose

I have an question about the service names in docker-compose.yml files.
Is there any convention for the naming?

I have following example (docker-compose.yml):

This example does not work when I run docker-compose. The log files tell me, that my node app could not find the express module:

```
nodejs:
  build: ./docker_node_js
  volumes:
    - "./docker_node_js/app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
```

On the other hand this example just works fine. I only changed the naming:

```
nodeweb:
  build: ./docker_node_js
  volumes:
    - "./docker_node_js/app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000"
```

Is there any naming convention? I searched through the docker-compose.yml reference but could not find anything. Maybe I just missed something in the documentation?

Greets 
Daniel

Comment: I don't see any difference between your two different docker-compose.yaml snippet. Maybe a wrong copy/past ?

Comment: You are right! My Bad! I changed the naming from the second yml-file from nodejs to nodeweb